# Site Republica Virtual fora do ar

Tags: java, xml, web-service, cep

Já a alguns dias o site [Republica Virtual](http://republicavirtual.com.br/cep/) que servia como base para muita gente realizar consulta de CEP e receber os dados com facilidade, esta fora do ar, não sei se alguém sabe o motivo de estar fora mas o meu questionamento é se existe outra fonte confiável por onde podemos extrair tais dados.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/4337)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O próprio site dos correios tem um serviço:
https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consigo ver o WSDL mas dá erro no parse dizendo que `The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'cliente'`

Comment: Faça um teste com um projeto novo e verifique se o problema ocorre.

Comment: Fiz direto no `WcfTestClient`, sem projeto nem nada e ocorreu o erro. Tentando consumir como `ServiceReference` num projeto novo também deu problema.